# How can I add a shadow or gradient effect to the application background, similar to the image shown?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I add a shadow or gradient effect to the application background, similar to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfLfg.png)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these [examples](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/brush), such as below and adjust accordingly:

```
val colorStops = arrayOf(
    0.0f to Color.Yellow,
    0.2f to Color.Red,
    1f to Color.Blue
)
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .requiredSize(200.dp)
        .background(Brush.horizontalGradient(colorStops = colorStops))
)
```